# node is not recognized as an internal or external command but node.exe -v giving result

Tags: node.js, windows-7-x64

I installed node in my winodws system, when i type node -v it is showing
**'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command**
I have node instalation directory in my system path
[image]

When i do **node.exe -v** it is working fine same for the npm, when i do **npm.cmd -v** it is showeing the version information
I know this is some windows path issue could anyone help me on this.

FYI: I installed 10.15.0 node.

EDIT: Adding echo %PATHEXT%
[image]

Comment: You have to set an enviroment variable in Windows. But you could also use the node.js command line tool which is installed during the node.js installation

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo %PATHEXT%` please?

Comment: is not a good practice but, did you try a cmd with admin permissions?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes tried with admin permissions but same problem.

Comment: This is your _PATHEXT_? There should be extensions in this variable, not paths. Try `SET PATHEXT=.EXE;.BAT;.CMD` and see if it works.

Comment: I suggest you add the output of the commands as a code block (place 4 spaces, followed by the copied output of the console), I'm on mobile now, and cannot read it, so I cannot offer support at the moment

Comment: @tkausl Thanks it worked, i Don't know which caused this issue I added 
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC  To my pathext.
Thanks again.